# C++ Problem with polymorphed methods in vector of pointers

Tags: pointers, methods, vector, polymorphism

first and foremost sorry for my bad english, I'm no english native =/

I have a vector of pointers directing at my base class A which is filled by classes B and C. 
B and C are polymorphic classes from A, which have only one more method, setTest().
Now I want to call a method from B/C through the vector:

```
vector (A*) vec;
vec.push_back(new classB());
vec.push_back(new classC());

for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    vec[i]->setTest(true);
```

But the compiler says there is no method setTest() in my baseclass A.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: is virtual void setTest(bool); declared in class A?

Comment: could we see a little more code? (Preferably the minimal amount that fails...)

Comment: No, does it have to be? That's part of a examn where the methods are strictly given

Comment: More code of the class D, where the fail happens:

#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
D::D(void)
{
   vector (A*) vec;
vec.push_back(new classB());
vec.push_back(new classC());

for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    vec[i]->setTest(true);
}

do you want any more?

Comment: Should be `vector<A*>`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since compiler "think" that deals with A, it cannot deduce that method `setTest` exists.

To resolve this problem you can do following:

Add abstract method to A:

```
 virtual void setTest(bool value) = 0;
```

**Update**

There is another way. Let's create helper interface D with only one method:

```
 struct D
 {
     virtual void setTest(bool value) = 0;
 };
```

Than using multiple inheritance change signature of B and C:

```
class B : public A, public D
{
     virtual void setTest(bool value)
     {
         //your impl goes here...
     }
};

//do the same with impl of C
```

And at last let's change iteration:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    ((D*)vec[i])->setTest(true);
```

Simple casting allows call expected method. BUT!!! if vector can contains instances of A than it will fail, so using dynamic_cast helps:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
{
     D *check_inst = dynamic_cast<D*>(vec[i]);
     if( check_inst)
        check_inst->setTest(true);
}
```

Comment: I assume there aren't any other ways to get arround this without adding the methods (if abstract or not) to the base class?

Comment: Fails again: Instance of abstract class cannot be created =(

Comment: I hate to keep going on about this, but I think we need to see *all* of the code, formatted nicely, as it actually goes through the compiler. E.G., where did you try to add this line? It should be inside the class...